# Before Adam(A.S) what thing was existing in this world

Tags: prophet-adam

Before Adam(A.S) which thing was existing on this earth?

Comment: As is the answer of this question can be about anything starting with dinosaurs etc. consider giving your question a focus and see [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know most certainly that **Jinn** existed before Adam(A.S) as well as the **Angels** , they were both present by the time of Adam(A.S)'s creation  .
Also Jinn lived on earth before us , precisely they were already living on earth when Adam (A.S) was created  , so here is your answer .

Comment: According to nonmuslim. Is non muslim beleave such a story

Comment: Evidences supporting your claims would make this answer more profitable. @user274225 IMO Jinn and Angels are Creations and I would hardly describe them as a "thing"!